# Factor out build matrix and share between multiple `Jenkinsfile`s

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

In the following `Jenkinsfile` I'm specifying a rather verbose build `matrix` ... and I'd like to use this in multiple projects, but without copy-pasting it to all the `Jenkinsfile`s. Is there a way to write a Groovy function (in shared library) that enables me to share the same matrix configuration in multiple `Jenkinsfile`s with minimal addition?

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'nixos'
    }
    options {
        parallelsAlwaysFailFast()
    }
    stages {
        stage ('OS Matrix') {
            matrix {
                agent {
                    label "${OS}"
                }
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'OS'
                        values 'nixos', 'macos'
                    }
                    axis {
                        name 'SYSTEM'
                        values 'x86_64-linux', 'aarch64-darwin', 'x86_64-darwin'
                    }
                }
                excludes {
                    exclude {
                        axis {
                            name 'OS'
                            values 'nixos'
                        }
                        axis {
                            name 'SYSTEM'
                            notValues 'x86_64-linux'
                        }
                    }
                    exclude {
                        axis {
                            name 'OS'
                            values 'macos'
                        }
                        axis {
                            name 'SYSTEM'
                            notValues 'aarch64-darwin', 'x86_64-darwin'
                        }
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage ('Cachix setup') {
                        steps {
                            cachixUse "nammayatri"
                        }
                    }
                    stage ('Nix Build All') {
                        steps {
                            nixBuildAll system: env.SYSTEM
                        }
                    }
                    stage ('Cachix push') {
                        steps {
                            cachixPush "nammayatri"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'nixos'
    }
    options {
        parallelsAlwaysFailFast()
    }
    inMatrix (nixos: ['x86_64-linux'], macos: ['x86_64-darwin' 'aarch64-darwin']) {
        stages {
            stage ('Cachix setup') {
                steps {
                    cachixUse "nammayatri"
                }
            }
            stage ('Nix Build All') {
                steps {
                    nixBuildAll system: env.SYSTEM
                }
            }
            stage ('Cachix push') {
                steps {
                    cachixPush "nammayatri"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to define this `inMatrix` function?